# IntelliJ IDEA does not display TypeScript errors when Vue framework being used

Tags: typescript, vue.js, intellij-idea

In below experiment, I have assigned the numeric value to the constant annotated as string.
The ESLint complains that I have not used this variable, but TypeScirpt is silent.

[image]

This happen when Vue framework is being used in the project.
Let me show what IntelliJ IDEA will display in the project where there is no Vue framework:

[image]

I have been faced with this problem before and there was the solution.
Although the Webpack does not need the target files and directories been explicitly specified in **tsconfig.json**, IDE does. So **include** option has solved the problem for a while:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    // ...
  },
  "include": [
    "Project.d.ts",
    "Source/**/*",
    "Tests/**/*"
  ]
}
```

But now, the problem has revived.
Herewith, the TypeScript error does not display in the plain TypeScript file below **Source**.

Something else IntelliJ IDEA needs, or it is just the bug?

### Appendix

#### The bottom bar

[image]

#### Full TypeScript configuration

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false, /* Actual for Vue3; see https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/4668 */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true, /* Actual for Vue3; */
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@Source/*": [ "./Source/*" ],
      "@Components/*": [ "./Source/Components/*"],
      "@SVG_Icons/*": [ "./Source/SVG_Icons/*"]
    },
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "Project.d.ts",
    "Source/**/*",
    "Tests/**/*"
  ]
}
```

#### The TypeScript configuration in IDE

[image]

Comment: This happens in .ts file and not .vue, right? Did you try to disable IDE linter?

Comment: @EstusFlask, Thank you for the comment. "This happens in .ts file and not .vue, right?" - Right. "Did you try to disable IDE linter?" - No. Why is it required?

Comment: Because you see linter error where TS error is expected, it would be useful to know what happens when there's no linter error. Looks like IDE issue so far

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce it. Please submit an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB and provide a sample project (no production code but the same structure and configs). Thanks!